# isc-dhcp-server problem when changing subnet IP net

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dhcp

I've got Linux set up in VirtualBox. To practice things for school I was trying to make isc-dhcp-server work but I've got a weird problem. DHCP server works only with this configuration:

```
    # A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
subnet 192.168.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.5.100 192.168.5.110;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
  option domain-name "something.local";
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.5.255;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.5.254;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
#
}
```

And Linux LAN adapter ip: `192.168.5.1/24`
With such configuration everything works just fine on Windows 7.
If I only change ip addressing to for example:

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.110;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
  option domain-name "something.local";
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.1.255;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.1.254;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
#
}
```

And Linux LAN adapter ip to: `192.168.1.1/24` DHCP doesn't work.
I do restart isc-dhcp-server after making any changes in `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`
I've got this homework in which I have to configure the DHCP for 172.16.19.0 network, how do I do it, what am I doing wrong? Could please somebody help me to get this to work?

Comment: You not only have to restart the isc-dhcp-server, you will also have to restart all the clients (or at least get them to toss out their old lease and get a new one). You might also have to delete the entire `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` file so that the system can start again creating a new one (not sure).

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean:

> DHCP doesn't work

Different symptom references to different issues. 
There can be many possible problems likely on routing or interface state or configuration.

Try `dhcpd -d *interface*` on server or `dhclient -d *interface*` on client, maybe `cat /var/log/syslog | grep DHC*` to check whether packets are sent successfully, or try `ip route show' ,`ip neigh show` then(not sure it would help, but since I dont have enough reputation to comment, I have to answer). Hope it helps.

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. Until you have earned sufficient reputation to comment, consider answering questions that don't need clarification, or suggesting edits to improve existing questions and answers. - [From Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/late-answers/788143)